# Jquery Toggle between views

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am sure this code works as I've used on many projects before but for some reason its not working, not sure if I've missed something out as its been a long time since i used JavaScript.

```
$("#history").click(function(){
    $('.apphome').hide();
    $('.history').show();
},function(){
    $('.apphome').show();
    $('.history').hide();
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="apphome">
   <h2>Dashboard</h2>
</div> 
<div class="history">
    <h2>History</h2>     
</div>
<li><a href="#" id="history" data-icon="refresh">History</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this be easier?

```
$("#history").click(function(){
    $('.apphome, .history').toggle();
});
```

Just make sure one of the 2 elements has `display:none` set in it's style, on page load. That way, the `toggle()` will toggle the visibility of both elements, alternating which of the 2 is displayed.

Comment: Sorry not sure why i complicated like i did. Thanks :)

Comment: That's what happens when you don't use a language for some time :P No problem!